# How to parse specific strings from an attribute inside xml using etree and xpath

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I have an XML with two of the same tags and same attribute but different value.

```
<testsuite>
 <testcase>
  <GenericItem html="Name: Epsilon&lt;br/&gt;ID: ID-032&lt;br/&gt;Owner: Infinitie &lt;a 
   href=&quot;mailto: infinitie@company.com 
   &quot;&gt;infinitie@company.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Revision ID: ataaaa">
   Algorithm:
  </GenericItem>
  <GenericItem html="No numerical differences between 'Model AB' and 'Baseline A' 
   found.&lt;/font&gt;">
   Results for 'Epsilon Model-01':
  </GenericItem>
 </testcase>
 <testcase>
   <GenericItem html="Name: ZeroG&lt;br/&gt;ID: ID-033&lt;br/&gt;Owner: Lite &lt;a 
   href=&quot;mailto: lite@company.com 
   &quot;&gt;lite@company.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Revision ID: ataaab">
   Algorithm:
  </GenericItem>
  <GenericItem html="No numerical differences between 'Model A' and 'Baseline B' found.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;green&quot;&gt;No performance difficulties found.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;red&quot;&gt;Target memory footprint more than 1.4 of baseline.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Applied tolerance from model configuration: 2e-13&lt;br/&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;green&quot;&gt;No numerical differences between 'Baseline B' and 'Target - Model A' found.&lt;/font&gt;">
   Results for 'Lite Model':
  </GenericItem>
 </testcase>
</testSuite>
```

The data that I want to get are :

1. Results for '#### Model'
2. Numerical Differences (if not listed then print ("NULL")
3. Performance Difficulties (if not listed then print ("NULL")
4. Memory footprint (if not listed then print ("NULL")
5. Tolerance Model applied (if not listed then print ("NULL")
6. The other numerical differences (if not listed then print ("NULL")

The code for now are :

```
from lxml import etree as ET


html_parser = ET.HTMLParser()
tree = ET.parse('NewestReport.xml')


test = tree.findall('testcase')
root = tree.getroot()
count = 0
count1 = 0
i = 0
for person in tree.xpath('./testcase'):
    a = person.xpath('//text()[contains(.,"Results")]')[i]
    print(a.strip())
    b = person.xpath('.//@html/text()[contains(., "tolerance")]')[i]
    if b:
        print(b.strip())
    else:
        print("None")
    i = i + 1
```

I manage to get the `Results for '#### Model'` but for the `Tolerance Model applied (if not listed then print ("NULL")` it outputs the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think it is because the no 'tolerance' is found on the first . But I can't seem to fix the error. Can someone help enlighten me on this problem ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `i`.

Comment: maybe first use `print(i)` to see for what value you get error `IndexError: list index out of range` - because it seems you use too big value. Probably you use it in wrong way. Maybe you should use only `person` without `[i]`

Comment: as for me you should get `<GenericItem>` and later use `attrib('html')` to get string with HTML which has expected values and parse it (to extract expected values)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you forgot `.` to create relative path to - and then you don't need `[i]` but always `[0]`

```
a = person.xpath('.//text()[contains(.,"Results")]')[0]
```

And in second part you should search in `@html` instead of `text()`

And you should also use `[0]` but after checking `if`

```
b = person.xpath('.//@html[contains(., "tolerance")]') 

if b:
    print(b[0].strip().split('<br/>'))
else:
    print("None")
```

---

Minimal working example with data directly in code

```
text = '''<testsuite>
 <testcase>
  <GenericItem html="Name: Epsilon&lt;br/&gt;ID: ID-032&lt;br/&gt;Owner: Infinitie &lt;a 
   href=&quot;mailto: infinitie@company.com 
   &quot;&gt;infinitie@company.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Revision ID: ataaaa">
   Algorithm:
  </GenericItem>
  <GenericItem html="No numerical differences between 'Model AB' and 'Baseline A' 
   found.&lt;/font&gt;">
   Results for 'Epsilon Model-01':
  </GenericItem>
 </testcase>
 <testcase>
   <GenericItem html="Name: ZeroG&lt;br/&gt;ID: ID-033&lt;br/&gt;Owner: Lite &lt;a 
   href=&quot;mailto: lite@company.com 
   &quot;&gt;lite@company.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Revision ID: ataaab">
   Algorithm:
  </GenericItem>
  <GenericItem html="No numerical differences between 'Model A' and 'Baseline B' found.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;green&quot;&gt;No performance difficulties found.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;red&quot;&gt;Target memory footprint more than 1.4 of baseline.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Applied tolerance from model configuration: 2e-13&lt;br/&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;green&quot;&gt;No numerical differences between 'Baseline B' and 'Target - Model A' found.&lt;/font&gt;">
   Results for 'Lite Model':
  </GenericItem>
 </testcase>
</testsuite>
'''

from lxml import etree as ET

html_parser = ET.HTMLParser()
#tree = ET.parse('NewestReport.xml')
tree = ET.fromstring(text)

for person in tree.xpath('./testcase'):
    a = person.xpath('.//text()[contains(.,"Results")]')[0]
    print(a.strip())
    print('---')
    
    b = person.xpath('.//@html[contains(., "tolerance")]')
    if b:
        print(b[0].strip().split('<br/>'))
    else:
        print("None")
    print('----------------')
```

Result:

```
Results for 'Epsilon Model-01':
---
None
----------------
Results for 'Lite Model':
---
No numerical differences between 'Model A' and 'Baseline B' found.</font>
<font color="green">No performance difficulties found.</font>
<font color="red">Target memory footprint more than 1.4 of baseline.</font>
Applied tolerance from model configuration: 2e-13
<font color="green">No numerical differences between 'Baseline B' and 'Target - Model A' found.</font>
----------------
```

For getting `Numerical Differences`, `Performance Difficulties`,
etc. I would use normal `string functions` or `regex`.